# Is the writer a man or woman?

Tags: code-golf, natural-language

One problem on a website like this is that you often don't know if you are talking to a male or female. However, you have come up with a simple NLP technique you can use to determine the gender of the writer of a piece of text.

## Theory

About 38.1% of letters used in English are vowels **[a,e,i,o,u]** (see References below, `y` is NOT a vowel in this case). Therefore, we will define any word that is at least 40% vowels as a *feminine word*, and any word that is less than 40% vowels as a *masculine word*.

Beyond this definition we can also find the *masculinity* or *femininity* of a word. Let *C* be the number of consonants in the word, and *V* be the number of vowels:

- If a word is feminine, it's femininity is `1.5*V/(C+1)`.
- If a word is masculine, it's masculinity is `C/(1.5*V+1)`.

For example, the word `catch` is masculine. Its masculinity is `4/(1.5*1+1) = 1.6`.  The word `phone` is feminine. Its femininity is `1.5*2/(3+1) = .75`.

## Algorithm

To figure out the gender of the writer of a piece of text, we take the sum of the masculinity of all the masculine words (Σ<sub>M</sub>), and the sum of the femininity of all the feminine words (Σ<sub>F</sub>). If Σ<sub>M</sub> > Σ<sub>F</sub>, we have determined that the writer is a male. Otherwise, we have determined that the writer is a female.

## Confidence Level

Finally, we need a confidence level. If you have determined that the writer is female, your confidence level is `2*ΣF/(ΣF+ΣM)-1`. If you have determined that the writer is male, the confidence level is `2*ΣM/(ΣF+ΣM)-1`.

## Input

Input is a piece of English text including punctuation. Words are all separated by spaces (You don't have to worry about new-lines or extra spaces). Some words have non-letter characters in them, which you need to ignore (such as "You're"). If you encounter a word that is all non-letters (like "5" or "!!!") just ignore it. Every input will contain at least one usable word.

## Output

You need to output an M or F depending on which gender you think the writer is, followed by your confidence level.

## Examples

1. `There's a snake in my boot.`

   - Gender + masculinity/femininity of each word: `[M1.0,F1.5,F.75,F.75,M2.0,F1.0]`
   - Σ<sub>M</sub> = 3.0, Σ<sub>F</sub> = 4.0
   - CL: `2*4.0/(4.0+3.0)-1` = .143
   - Output: `F .143`
2. `Frankly, I don't give a ^$*.`

   - `[M2.4,F1.5,M1.2,F1.0,F1.5]`, Σ<sub>M</sub> = 3.6, Σ<sub>F</sub> = 4.0, CL: `2*4.0/(4.0+3.6)-1` =  .053, Output: `F .053`
3. `I'm 50 dollars from my goal!`

   - `[F.75,M1.25,M1.2,M2.0,F1.0]`, Σ<sub>M</sub> = 4.45, Σ<sub>F</sub> = 1.75, CL: `2*4.45/(4.45+1.75)-1` = .435, Output: `M .435`

## References

1. [Percentage of vowels in English dictionary words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#Relative_frequencies_of_letters_in_the_English_language) (38.1%)
2. [Percentage of vowels in English texts](http://www.sttmedia.com/characterfrequency-english) (38.15%)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62626/discussion-on-question-by-geokavel-is-the-writer-a-man-or-woman).

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>320</s> <s>317</s> <s>307</s> <s>286</s> <s>253</s> 189 bytes

```python
h=S=0
for v in input().split():V=sum(map(v.count,'aeiouAEIOU'));C=sum(x.isalpha()for x in v);H=V<.4*C;C-=V;K=[1.5*V/(C+1),C/(1.5*V+1)][H];h+=K*H;S+=K-K*H
print('FM'[h>S],2*max(S,h)/(S+h)-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HU/RasIwFH3PV9zJoEmt1W7zxS6DURRFhg91fREHWY2m2DYhSbv267tUuHDO5Zx7uEf1Vsj6dcjlhdPJZDIImtIFukoNLRS1G9VYTEKjysLhKqOmqXDFFG7DXDa1DTzGC9l8rneHb4@QOHkYurAwrFSCYTJGdWNUS@Itzd7DNz@JkxnN4j09ReHSz@Y4mUYkSOb4sTp@Pm3PsZjSvb@NUwczR5DSRW2xt/nyTuIjPQcvfsU6nAaCzHE6FWQWkcE1QFb3KwTwJ4qSw1E3fNwAeMdzPNYkiHc5VxbWh81aa6lHXTFjhqPgmnsGGJia3fn4dNXDr5Q2RBvN6nvZB7CDi6w9C7ei5c758@yHaOdVsFw4oSyZNnDVshovb5KVT/8)

**Ungolfed**:

```python
def evaluateWord(s):
    V = len([*filter(lambda c: c in 'aeiou', s.lower())])
    C = len([*filter(lambda c: c in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxzwy', s.lower())])
    isMasculine = V < 0.4*(V+C)
    return C/(1.5*V+1) if isMasculine else 1.5*V/(C+1), isMasculine


def evaluatePhrase(s):
    scores = []
    for word in s.split():
        scores.append(evaluateWord(word))
    masc = 0
    fem = 0
    for score in scores:
        if score[1]:
            masc += score[0]
        else:
            fem += score[0]
    return ('M', 2*masc/(fem+masc)-1) if masc > fem else ('F', 2*fem/(fem+masc)-1)


print(evaluatePhrase("There's a snake in my boot."))
```

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by using semicolons and putting all of the first function on one line. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7NboMwEITveYpVLqzBJaQ/F1L3glTlUikSFVKEOBCy1DSOobbTJH15CqlSqVKPMzs783VnJ1t91/dbqoHQ8koo0nwl6kY5MizOeCIqzP0VqnK/2ZZQxRU0GrySmvbgcRuq9kgGGSsY/ze4qbb1m3zfqb3uPox1n6ev4/nv42IpsscovPcxCxK2MOQORkMyw3n44GfBnDU1LIGUJbg4M0wGky8nI3U3UEsR8VRELJ5A3RpYD8M54YmN4jRS2NB2qnHIiiECQ906nxexDMQ6j4rBGbvj9Cp/ANB78fitL2eYBpLdXCjkU3rJovc83tLfW9@ZRjvscPoqyZBnoQSryx2N6/szbNrWhVPG@m8 "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @ComradeSparklePony thanks!

Comment: `map(e,s.split())` instead of `[e(x)for x in s.split()]`

Comment: Also, it's better to `return'FM'[h>S],2*max(S,h)/(S+h)-1` at the end

Comment: I looked up a more efficient way to count vowels/consonants via `sum(map(s.count,chars))`, dropping your count to [253 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY5Nb4JAEIbv/oqpacIubFHaetHSC4nRQ080JIbQZMXFpe4H3V1U@ucp2tSkt3nfPDPPNJ3jWj31vYwlbUY7VgFDFs9HUMY2LHWr3CIjSWxbiSQqiUdZrVsPY3JrtuWu2vPPg5Cq@TLWHc/fp24gFqs4ewmffZQFCV4Y5lqj8iic@dkEJUGESTJB1zjMRb4qyOqqb5AlPJ6SNJ5e3qi0gQ3UCiRixIZCn5hBOLSNqB3CFwLqCjZ5VMx5EG/yaTE0TFg2T//ir9pbvnk5f00L8uhLekYp4XiC0oDjh6hvTK0catD4nTPDPAsUrKIHdhV3sNXahWOMRzduaag6iI7AGnZaeQ729ZENWx/3/n9w7UmYTQdICGosVEbLy8W9puJuAPsf "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: [Golfed to 189 bytes](https://tio.run/##HU/RasIwFH3PV9zJoEmt1W7zxS6DURRFhg91fREHWY2m2DYhSbv267tUuHDO5Zx7uEf1Vsj6dcjlhdPJZDIImtIFukoNLRS1G9VYTEKjysLhKqOmqXDFFG7DXDa1DTzGC9l8rneHb4@QOHkYurAwrFSCYTJGdWNUS@Itzd7DNz@JkxnN4j09ReHSz@Y4mUYkSOb4sTp@Pm3PsZjSvb@NUwczR5DSRW2xt/nyTuIjPQcvfsU6nAaCzHE6FWQWkcE1QFb3KwTwJ4qSw1E3fNwAeMdzPNYkiHc5VxbWh81aa6lHXTFjhqPgmnsGGJia3fn4dNXDr5Q2RBvN6nvZB7CDi6w9C7ei5c758@yHaOdVsFw4oSyZNnDVshovb5KVT/8)

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-ap`, <s>154</s> 140 bytes

`-ap` loops over input and splits on spaces, storing the result in `$F`, then outputs `$_` after the program finishes.

```ruby
m=f=0
$F.map{s=_1.upcase.gsub(/[^A-Z]/){}
k=s.size-v=s.count('AEIOU')
k>v*1.5?m+=k/(1.5*v+1):f+=1.5*v/-~k}
$_=m>f ??M:?F,2*[m,f].max/(m+f)-1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY7NSsNAFIX3eYprCeR3Jo1QkMIkdGEgC3FjN4a0TOtMDJPJhEwSjKU-gW_gxoXizvfp2xi1q_PBPefc8_bR9rvxK5sh2szy76bvNJQcTAwRhJ99x9HV6VUSTuaGmWBJm4Mm2xD3zZ5qhgvd7-wg26zQfR44h6MhiMa6fGZomGCv-rqzrdV1eru2HENEgxviRSw9IgJ7InfwQmfJPfLHAXoRR8PcEhlxiOObZZz4l24mfZ5Pf58CW3rcQedN72c5re8eWcssDRR0TQWDsgY5wk6pDhtJS2tRjT6k8KBqq4OiHNjk3JguNlJLwmI-HaqKthp4q-RvslC0uvhv_wE)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>205 201 197</s> 192 bytes

-Thanks @Value Ink for 4 bytes: `lower()` beforehand
-Thanks @Coty Johnathan Saxman for 9 bytes: Inverted condition `.4*(v+c)>v` and `-~c` for `(c+1)` bitshift-based consonant check instead of literal.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 192 bytes

```python
M=F=0
for i in input().lower().split():
 v=sum(j in'aeiou'for j in i);c=sum(33021815<<98>>ord(k)&1for k in i)
 if.4*(v+c)>v:M+=c/(1.5*v+1)
 else:F-=1.5*v/~c
print('FM'[M>F],2*max(M,F)/(F+M)-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3NboMwEITvPMX2UtuQAA5FSknM0VIPfoKqB4tA6sTGlvlJk0NfnTpUGmm1M99o3H38tn2xLIJxlked9aBA9UFuGjFJtb21PtzBaRX@KoKZDZPBl0Ag2So7oWfnsnbIoVnDosh3dE/L4/F9X9fWn/CVvNInd/3nIlBd@hbjOWlIPVciYU2GaVrGc0JD2OqhrfiWrU7220TOq37EiAv0KWr@tdnFRv5gseEkwzwRZEvJsnwgA2UOJ6u19AN03howd3Dq8ZDgpNdh/2ylfvkD)

Comment: `for i in input().lower().split():` so that you only need to look in `'aeiou'` for the vowel count and cut the `lower` call in the consonant count.

Comment: In your 'else', the divisor (c+1) can be shortened to -~c, with no parentheses, saving a byte. This negative can then, in turn, be carried to your +=, making it a -= and saving one more byte. F-=1.5*v/~c

Comment: Switching the order of your inequality (in your if statement) saves you one more byte because you can delete the space. if.4*(v+c)>v

Comment: This is a tricky one, but you can save 5 bytes by switching your consonant lookup for a hardcoded binary lookup table. k in'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxzwy'for k... becomes 33021815<<98>>ord(k)&1for k... [https://tio.run/##JY3NboMwEITvPMX2UtuQAA5FSknM0VIPfoKqB4tA6sTGlvlJk0NfnTpUGmm1M99o3H38tn2xLIJxlked9aBA9UFuGjFJtb21PtzBaRX@KoKZDZPBl0Ag2So7oWfnsnbIoVnDosh3dE/L4/F9X9fWn/CVvNInd/3nIlBd@hbjOWlIPVciYU2GaVrGc0JD2OqhrfiWrU7220TOq37EiAv0KWr@tdnFRv5gseEkwzwRZEvJsnwgA2UOJ6u19AN03howd3Dq8ZDgpNdh/2ylfvkD Try it online!]

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>237</s> <s>229</s> <s>222</s> 216 bytes

Boy I though I could do this in a LOT LESS BYTES...

```c
v,c;float m,f;g(char*s){for(m=f=0;*s;v*1.0/(c+v)<.4?m+=c/(1.5*v+1):1?f+=1.5*v/(c+1):0,s+=*s!=0)for(v=c=0;*s&&*s^32;s++)isalpha(*s)?strchr("AaEeIiOoUu",*s)?++v:++c:0;printf("%c %.3f",m>f?77:70,(m>f?2*m:2*f)/(f+m)-1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1da8IwFIbv/RUxTM2XNdWJ0Cwru9jAq91st0KWNW2xaSSpARF/e9cKuxjsXL3n5TnP0ctS676PTAvTONUBy4woka6UJwFfjfPISiO5IEFEkiZ8hTSN@Cl5zC2VeoXSZEsiTXGW5obK@zYiQ8FZoJKEqeR41ESp75r5nITDZi0CpbgOqjlVCg2v8tB5XXkEX9Rrsa/f3ecZsrGnNGaU6oyLk6/bziA402CWbAxk9tnku1224wyNcU1stiYGr5ChFi9TLG69VXWL8OQ6AcOUCH5UhS8WASgQWnUsQN0CewFfznUJxOJ07gKCQ/jF37xqj82FgT34du2iA2Udi@H48ED@5fcLC7Z8YJtG@QCMd3b0l0410z/8bdL/AA)

Comment: [196 bytes](https://tio.run/##bYxNawIxFEX3/opnqJovdVREmHQqXbQwq27arRDjZAxOEknGoSL2r09HwUWhb3Xv5ZynxqVSbdtwJXTlZQ2Wa1FitZeBRnLRPmCb6SwRNIoFbZ7nVK0ty9QUzyZL2rAZSbEeZ/cy/VGER5b1@516M5tM3c3hkMbNYi4iY8REWR33EnfI2rhd8Y3Rq3wrcvPhv06I32bGmpQxlSbiGIyrNUYDBYPJQiNuX/R6tUpXCddyG7EdazLFmllCxLW10jhMepcedFdi9LkvQjGKICE6eSjAOLBn2HpfTxARx1MdMerCA38P0h2qM4ccdt6NaihNU3Ty5on@y@cjC8ukY6tKhgg6eHv7X3pZ9f/w1177Cw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 61 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ð¡εálžNžM‚δÃ€g©`3;*‚Â>/®¤sO/.4@©è®‚}0š.¡θ}€€нODZk„MFèsZ·sO/<‚
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8IZDC89tPbww5@g@v6P7fB81zDq35XDzo6Y16YdWJhhbawEFDjfZ6R9ad2hJsb@@nonDoZWHVxxaBxSuNTi6UA@oeUctUDUQXdjr7xKV/ahhnq/b4RXFUYe2A9XbANX9/x@SkVqUql6skKhQnJeYnaqQmaeQW6mQlJ9fogcA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/wxsOLTy39fDCnKP7/I7u833UMOvclsPNj5rWpB9amWBsrQUUONxkp39o3aElxf76eiYOh1YeXnFoHVC41uDoQj2g5h21QNVAdGGvv0tU9qOGeb5uh1cURx3aDlRvA1T3X@d/tFJyYklyhkJBRn5eqpKOUkhGalGqerFCokJxXmJ2qkJmnkJupUJSfn6JHlDWrSgxLzunUkfBUyElP0@9RCE9sywVqDZORQsk7ameq2BqAJTKyUksKlZIK8rPBelOz0/MUQRKJyYlK8UCAA).

**Explanation:**

Step 1: Split the input into words, and get the amount of consonants and vowels of each word:

```python
ð¡               # Split the (implicit) input-string by spaces
                 # (NOTE: builtin `#` doesn't work if the input is just a single word)
  ε              # Map over each word:
   á             #  Only leave its letters (removing any punctuation)
    l            #  And convert it to lowercase
     žN          #  Push the lowercase consonants: "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
       žM‚       #  Pair it with the vowels: ["bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz","aeiou"]
          δ      #  Map over both using the lowercase word:
           Ã     #   And only keep those characters
            €    #  Then map over the pair:
             g   #   And get the length of each
                 #  (we now have a pair [amount_of_consonants,amount_of_vowels],
                 #   let's call these [C,V] like in the challenge description)
              ©  #  Store this pair in variable `®` (without popping)
```

[Try step one online.](https://tio.run/##AUEAvv9vc2FiaWX//8OwwqHOtcOhbMW@TsW@TeKAms60w4Pigqxnwqn//1RoZXJlJ3MgYSBzbmFrZSBpbiBteSBib290Lg)

Step 2: Apply the formulas: \$\left[\frac{C}{1.5V+1},\frac{1.5V}{C+1}\right]\$

```python
   `             #  Pop and push both values separated to the stack
    3;*          #  Multiply V by 1.5 (3 halved)
       ‚         #  And pair it back together with C
        Â        #  Bifurcate; short for Duplicate & Reverse copy
         >       #  Increase both values in the reversed duplicate by 1
          /      #  Divide the pairs at the same positions:
                 #   [C/(V*1.5+1),V*1.5/(C+1)]
```

[Try the first two steps online.](https://tio.run/##AUwAs/9vc2FiaWX//8OwwqHOtcOhbMW@TsW@TeKAms60w4PigqxnwqlgMzsq4oCaw4I@L///VGhlcmUncyBhIHNuYWtlIGluIG15IGJvb3Qu)

Step 3: Check if the word was feminine or masculine by checking if the amount of vowels is at least 40%:

```python
   ®             #  Push the pair from variable `®` again
    ¤            #  Push its last item (without popping the pair): V
     s           #  Swap so the pair it at the top of the stack again
      O          #  Sum them together: C+V
       /         #  Divide them: V/(C+V)
        .4@      #  Check if this is larger than or equal to 0.4
                 #  (1 if >=0.4; 0 if <0.4)
           ©     #  Store this boolean as new `®` (without popping)
            è    #  0-based index it into the [C/(V*1.5+1),V*1.5/(C+1)]-pair
             ®‚  #  And pair it together with boolean `®`
  }              # Close the map
```

[Try the first three steps online.](https://tio.run/##AWAAn/9vc2FiaWX//8OwwqHOtcOhbMW@TsW@TeKAms60w4PigqxnwqlgMzsq4oCaw4I@L8KuwqRzTy8uNEDCqcOowq7igJp9//9UaGVyZSdzIGEgc25ha2UgaW4gbXkgYm9vdC4)

Step 4: Group all masculine and feminine values together:

```python
   0š            # Prepend a 0 to the list of pairs
                 # (this is to ensure the first group are the falsey/masculine pairs;
                 #  and the second group the truthy/feminine pairs)
     .¡          # Group the pairs (and the leading 0) by:
       θ         #  Their last item, which is the boolean
      }€         # After the group-by, map over each group:
        €        #  Map over each inner pair:
         н       #   And only leave the first item
```

[Try the first four steps online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8IZDC89tPbww5@g@v6P7fB81zDq35XDzo6Y16YdWJhhbawEFDjfZ6R9ad2hJsb@@nonDoZWHVxxaBxSuNTi6UA@oeUctUDUQXdj7/39IRmpRqnqxQqJCcV5idqpCZp5CbqVCUn5@iR4A).

Step 5: Get the sums of both groups, and check if the masculine or feminine sum is larger:

```python
O                # Take the sum of each inner group
 D               # Duplicate this pair of sums
  Z              # Get the maximum (without popping the pair itself)
   k             # Get the index of this maximum in the pair (0 or 1)
    „MFè         # Index it into the string "MF"
```

[Try the first five steps online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8IZDC89tPbww5@g@v6P7fB81zDq35XDzo6Y16YdWJhhbawEFDjfZ6R9ad2hJsb@@nonDoZWHVxxaBxSuNTi6UA@oeUctUDUQXdjr7xKV/ahhnq/b4RX//4dkpBalqhcrJCoU5yVmpypk5inkViok5eeX6AEA).

Step 6: Apply the confidence formula: \$\frac{2\max\left(\sum{F},\sum{M}\right)}{\sum{F}+\sum{M}}-1\$

```python
        s        # Swap so the duplicated pair of sums is at the top again
         Z       # Get the maximum again (without popping)
          ·      # Double this maximum
           s     # Swap so the pair is at the top of the stack again
            O    # Sum them together
             /   # Divide the doubled maximum by this sum
              <  # Decrease it by 1
```

[Try the first six steps online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8IZDC89tPbww5@g@v6P7fB81zDq35XDzo6Y16YdWJhhbawEFDjfZ6R9ad2hJsb@@nonDoZWHVxxaBxSuNTi6UA@oeUctUDUQXdjr7xKV/ahhnq/b4RXFUYe2A9Xb/P8fkpFalKperJCoUJyXmJ2qkJmnkFupkJSfX6IHAA).

Step 7: And finally pair the two results together, and output it as result:

```python
               ‚ # And pair it together with the "M"/"F"
                 # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>336</s> <s>328</s> <s>297</s> <s>286</s> <s>278</s> <s>276</s> 260 bytes

```js
t=>['FM'[+(g=((m=(r=s=>t.split` `.map(c=>[p=(v=(c=[...c][u='filter'](a=>/[a-zA-Z]/.test(a)))[u](a=>/[aeiouAEIOU]/.test(a)).length)>=(q=c.length)*.4?0:1,p?(q-v)/(1.5*v+1):1.5*v/(q-v+1)])[u](e=>e[0]==s).reduce((a,c)=>a+c[1],0))(1))>(f=r(0))))],2*(g?m:f)/(f+m)-1]
```

This took me a really long time to golf but it still is 260 bytes long.

*-8 bytes thanks to my own efforts: removed `return` statement and curly braces*

*-31 bytes thanks to my own efforts: replaced long alphabet string literal inclusion test with regular expression test: why did I not think of that before. Code is also becoming more and more unreadable as time goes by.*

*-11 bytes thanks to my own efforts: come to think of it, why not replace the other `includes` as well?*

*-8 bytes thanks to my own efforts: noticed similarity between possible confidence levels and refactored*

*-2 bytes thanks to my own efforts: new `q` variable set to `c[h]` used multiple times.*

*day 2 of golfing super-long answer: -16 bytes thanks to my own efforts*

Ungolfed:

```js
function determine(text) {
    let words = text.split(' ');
    words = words.map(cur => {
        cur = [...cur].filter(a=>"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".includes(a.toLowerCase())).join``;
        let vowels = [...cur].filter(a=>"aeiou".includes(a.toLowerCase())).length;
        let output = [vowels>=cur.length/2.5?'f':'m'];
        output.push(output[0]=='m'?(cur.length-vowels)/(1.5*vowels+1):1.5*vowels/(cur.length-vowels+1));
        return output;
    });
    let femi = words.filter(e=>e[0]=='f').reduce((a,c)=>a+c[1],0);
    let masc = words.filter(e=>e[0]=='m').reduce((a,c)=>a+c[1],0);
    let gender = (masc>femi?'m':'f');
    let confidence = (gender=='f'?2*femi/(femi+masc)-1:2*masc/(femi+masc)-1);
    console.log(gender , confidence);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 404 bytes

```
(defun f(x &aux(a 0)c(f 0)m v u)(labels((w(x &aux(p(position #\  x)))(cons(#1=subseq x 0 p)(and p(w(#1#x(1+ p)))))))(dolist(e(w(coerce x'list)))(setf v(#2=count-if(lambda(x)(member x(coerce"aeiouAEIOU"'list)))e)u(#2#'alpha-char-p e)c(- u v)m(and(> c 0)(<(/ v c)4/6)))(and(> u 0)(if m(incf a(/ c(1+(* v 3/2))))(incf f(/ v 2/3(1+ c))))))(format t"~:[F~;M~] ~4f~%"(> a f)(-(/(* 2(if(> a f)a f))(+ a f))1))))
```

Good old verbose lisp!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVHLbtQwFP2V06SQ65aQmWlh0VIkFlSaBWIDKx6S49gdq7Ed4nhIN/n16fV0GsmRdV73Hln1Ng6HA3XaJA9DM97KNJPESigy/HfYIwnqZav7SPT/VTHQEKKdbPAofwOzEIJU8JHK9V1MbdT/MGOFQZD0HQY2lutypvUlQy8fdYGHT6SZU0GPSmOuMpK5qCeDPZWbOxWSn2preAXXdpJmQU67Vo@YT7ZCahvSl6/b7z@L1wAtEpvLSvbDTtZqJ8d6gOZONRL2wuWt6DMUN6RP1HBJJa6bj3n0C5MyYw0cWa8MJGsUb08XLL1qNscCR8Yc3ZvmKndTp2omjE5OmIrl5tf9cvtt@YPl2ixvCk6WMIJqajhqwxNOSD6CLo93sc4hB@pDGMBRsID1qKj4sdOjriKropePOqPuCW0I0/sCxf0o/WP/9A5bdMFXEx7sXrP27/lFpreVw4cVU30vxwgzBpfdD0H2Z4VgHPzilgc/Aw)

Ungolfed version:

```
(defun f(x &aux (a 0) c (f 0) m v u)        ; parameter & auxiliary variables
  (labels ((w (x &aux (p (position #\  x))) ; recursive function to split input into words
              (cons (subseq x 0 p) (and p (w (subseq x (1+ p)))))))
    (dolist (e (w (coerce x 'list)))        ; for each word 
      (setf v (count-if (lambda (x) (member x(coerce"aeiouAEIOU"'list))) e) ; count vowels
            u (count-if 'alpha-char-p e)    ; count all alfabetic letters
            c (- u v)                       ; calculate consonants
            m (and (> c 0) (< (/ v c) 4/6))); is male or not?
      (and (> u 0)                          ; if non-empty word
           (if m
               (incf a (/ c (1+ (* v 3/2)))); increase masculinity
               (incf f (/ v 2/3 (1+ c)))))) ; increase femininity
    (format t "~:[F~;M~] ~4f"               ; print
              (> a f)                       ; “gender”
              (-(/ (* 2 (if (> a f)a f)) (+ a f)) 1))))  ; and confidence
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 147 bytes

```perl6
{{"{<M F>[[<] $_]} {2*.max/.sum-1}"}(@([Z+] map {my \v=1.5*.comb(rx:i/<[aeiou]>/);my \c=.comb(/<:L>/)-2*v/3;(c>v)*c/(v+1),(v>=c)*v/(c+1)},.words))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcxfT4MwFAXwdz/FlSzSMlZkZj6MP/FpyRJ925MMTdeVQUYpaVkdIXx27KKJPt57fue0XNXPk@gfimQaBmeI32CTZlmcw@wzH2FYekTQa0D0RSzC0RnRC8re5zkI2sIgetibJCQrjzApDkhd11UQZ5RX8pKnAY5ugCU/YRCvX@1vsfRM8BQhlhrssQCZeYh9ZNKEYRsgZs/RJ19SHTXG46RpDwU4u5Ir7mqgoBt65lA1YLcPUnbEie5@0UbR5lz3PmzhKBu3g1NluK187GfeP7Z1BaweLalrqjQUSorb2EnS@v5PMdqxEtpSNtyJpm8)